# Solution for an ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let the ODE
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+x-2}{y+x-4}$$

I got the general (implicit) solution:
$$y=\ln|x+y-3|+x+A$$ A is arbitrary constant.

My question is:
is $3=y+x$ a solution of this ODE? I know it's not contained in the general solution.

Comment: What about using z = x + y for an easier solution ? If you plug y = 3 - x, the ODE is satisfied.

Comment: I've already done that and found a general solution. However when I did this, I divided by z=3, so I need to check if this is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem here... The question asks if $y=3-x$ solves the ODE:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+x-2}{y+x-4},$$

If $y=3-x\Rightarrow y+x-2=1 \text{ and } y+x-4=-1$  and also $y^\prime =-1$.
So, yes since $-1=\frac{1}{-1}$ you have that $y(x)=3-x$ satisfies the ODE.

Answer (score 0):

substitute u=y+x-4

$$u=y+x-4\\u'=y'+1\\y'=u'-1\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+x-2}{y+x-4}\rightarrow \overset{u=y+x-4}{\rightarrow}\\
u'-1=\frac{u+2}{u}\\
u'=1+\frac{u+2}{u}\\
\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{2u+2}{u}\\
\frac{du}{\frac{2u+2}{u}}=dx\\
\int \frac{u}{2u+2}=\int dx$$